# TypeORM Throwing Duplication Error on Bulk saving instead of ignore or update existing value

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

As Documented on TypeOrm FrameWork `Repository.save` should save/insert new values and ignore/update the existing once,

But now I'm facing a problem that it's thrown a `duplication error` on existing value and stoping the whole inserting! ( I have a unique column called `key` )

**My entity:**

```js
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToOne, JoinColumn, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Source } from '../sources/source.entity';


@Entity({ name: 'articles' })
export class Article {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column({
        nullable: true
    })
    image: string | null;

    @Column({
        type: "text",
    })
    url: string;

    @Column({
        type: "varchar",
        unique: true
    })
    key: string;

    @Column({
        type: 'datetime',
        nullable: true
    })
    date: Date | null;

    @ManyToOne(type => Source, source => source.articles, {eager: true})
    @JoinColumn({name: 'source'})
    source: Source;

    @Column({
        type: `text`,
        nullable: true
    })
    description: string | null
}
```

**My Service:**

```js
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Article) private readonly articleRepository: Repository<Article>,
    private readonly articlesScraper: BlogScraperService
) {

}

async clonningFromScraper() {
    let articles = await this.articlesScraper.articles('1');

    articles = articles.map(article => ({ ...article, key: decodeURIComponent(article.url).substring(0, 255) }));

    return this.articleRepository
        .save(articles);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**I have ended up solving this by RAW SQL query using the following**

```js
return this.articleRepository.query(
    "INSERT IGNORE INTO articles ( title, date, url, image, source, description, _key ) VALUES ?", [querableArticles]);
```

Comment: If you prefer no using the query method, you can always use the queryBuilder solution:

```typescript
await connection.createQueryBuilder().insert().into(Post).values(post2).onConflict(`("id") DO NOTHING`).execute();
```



You can get more examples here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/test/functional/query-builder/insert-on-conflict/query-builder-insert-on-conflict.ts

Comment: unfortunately, this fix it doesn't work for me, still returning a `dup error` the code I tried `this.articleRepository
            .createQueryBuilder().insert().values(articles).onConflict(`("_key") DO NOTHING`).execute();`

Comment: The conflicting attribute is only the `_key`, right? This "guard" won't consume the duplication error, if there is another attribute, which also has a unique restriction.

Comment: I guess my primary key `id` but I don't pass it in my request.

Comment: ON CONFLICT statement is supported just for postgres and cockroach.

Comment: BTW, TypeORM now supports `orIgnore` method. [reference](http://typeorm-doc.exceptionfound.com/classes/insertquerybuilder.html#orignore)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to update the same record, which includes a unique constraint ( in your case, key ), first, you need to find the record from the DB and attach the ID to the new record that you want to update via the save method.